# HTML open link in the same window not a new tab

Tags: html

I am trying to open a link in the same window that I am working on but it doesn't work I get the message in the attached photo[image]

```html
 <body>

     <form>
     <select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target">
     <option value='none' selected>Choose a theme</option>
     <option value="https://google.com">Google</option>
     <option value="https://www.youtube.com">Youtube</option>
     <option value="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</option>
     </select>
     <input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage()" />
     </form>
     <script>
    
     function goToNewPage(){
     window.open(list.value, '_self')
   
     }
     </script>

     </body>
```

Comment: Why not use window.location = "url" ??

Comment: where I can replace this?  put in you consideration that I need the links open in the same window not a new Tabs

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
window.open(url,'_blank')
```

Comment: This opens new tab, I want to stay in the same window, how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use window.location = "Url" for that.

```js
function action() {
  window.location = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72602788/html-open-link-in-the-same-window-not-a-new-tab"
}
```

```html
<button onclick="action()">klick</button>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Answer (score 0):

You can go for

window.location.href=url

Answer (score 0):

here's what you can do with `window.open`

URL is loaded into a new window, or tab. This is the default

```
window.open(list.value, '_blank')
```

URL is loaded into the parent frame

```
window.open(list.value, '_parent')
```

URL replaces the current page

```
window.open(list.value, '_self')
```

URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded

```
window.open(list.value, '_top')
```

**Based on your conditions, you might want to use** `_parent` because `_self` is meant to open the page in case you are using an `<iframe>` which is not the case here. Try this one:

```html
 <body>

     <form>
     <select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target">
     <option value='none' selected>Choose a theme</option>
     <option value="https://google.com">Google</option>
     <option value="https://www.youtube.com">Youtube</option>
     <option value="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</option>
     </select>
     <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage()" />
     </form>
     <script>
    
     function goToNewPage(){
     window.open(list.value, '_parent')
   
     }
     </script>

     </body>
```

Be advised `window.open()` is a deprecated function and is no more used. you can try `window.location` for achieving the same. Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Comment: only `_blank` is working, I need the option of `_self` but still not working for me!

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can try it this way. Check if this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
<body>


        <form>
        <select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target">
        <option value='none' selected>Choose a theme</option>
        <option value="Google">Google</option>
        <option value="Youtube">Youtube</option>
        <option value="FB"></option>
        </select>
        <input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage()" />
        </form>
        <script>
       
        function goToNewPage(){
            switch(document.getElementById('list').value)
{
case "Google":
window.location="https://www.google.co.in";
break;

case "Youtube":
window.location="https://www.youtube.com";
break;

case "FB":
window.location="https://www.facebook.com";
break;

/// Can be extended to other different selections of SubCategory //////
default:
window.location="../"; // if no selection matches then redirected to home page
break;
}// end of switch 
}


      
</script>
   
       
  </body>
```

Try your Vs code it's working fine in the snippet it's not working correctly don't know what's wrong.

Comment: The title of this question says: "in the same window not a new tab"

Comment: this opens new window I want to stay in the same window

Comment: please check my updated code it's working in the  vs code but not in the snippet